# Former Dev removed reviews, wishlist, send to friend

Tags: magento-1.9, review, paths

Is there something controlling reviews, wishlist and send to friend at a higher level than the admin control?  A former dev removed the wishlist, reviews, send to a friend feature of the product page and didn't leave and code annotations as to the changes.

I've checked the System>Config>Advanced for my store view and all three are  enabled fully.  I've checked for Customers>Wishlist and its good to go.

There are a few reviews that were submitted, so clearly it worked to a point.  Reviews and ratings is what I'm after here.

I've checked view.phtml & list.phtml and nothing is commented out. All mentions of 'review' in the code seem nominal.

[Sample affected page](http://www.newvape.com/rosin-press-plates-4x6-inch/)

Should I be looking somewhere else for this? Surely he commented this out or worst case removed it! I can't find the exact location of where this could have been removed.  Any guidance down the file path would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways that they could be removed:

- **Removed with theme**. check the active theme's local.xml layout file for `<remove>` or `<action method="unsetChild">` calls
- **Removed by editing XML**. Check `wishlist.xml`. Compare it to the same file found in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/wishlist.xml`. Look for telltale signs of removal there (comments, deleted nodes). These changes could be in the base/default package *or* in the currently configured theme package
- **Removed by deleting the layout files themselves**. Check to see if the file `wishlist.xml` even exists. If it's missing it's likely that maybe the source of trouble.
- **Disabled in Admin**. Perhaps the module output is disabled in `System > Config > Advanced`
- **Hidden via CSS**. Perhaps they didn't remove it, but they hid it?

There are so many ways to do things in Magento that it may take some time investigating.

Best of luck.

Comment: Uggg.  Thanks for the leads.  Local.xml looks clean.  Wishlist, review.xml look clean as well.  Nothing commented out and code matches base.  I checked local.xml, and base/default as well.  Nada.  Admin is all enabled and I checked all store views.  Something is blocking the output of these three.